# How to print a string into an element?

Tags: pug

I use jade to create php templates. Is it possible to output a string like this using jade:

```
<div id="main" <?php print $attributes; ?>></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a solution which seems a bit hacky to me but it works:

```
#main&attributes({'<?php print $attributes; ?>': true})
```

will render to:

```
<div id="main" <?php print $attributes; ?>></div>
```

but only if you set your doctype to html5.

The trick is, treading the php snipped like a boolean attribute. [See documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#booleanattribs)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like the following, i'm not sure about the variable. You might need to make it a function like on the webpage.

```
#main
    p= attributes;
```

Use: http://phpmagazine.net/2010/11/jade-advanced-templating-engine-available-for-php.html

Comment: I think my question was misleading. I am trying to output the string above using jade including the `<?php  ?>` part.

Comment: As you can see on the webpage, the image (on the right) also uses the <?php ?> tags, which is translated to the left